# Handle orientations in Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

A want to create an Metro Style Windows 8 application that doesn't rotate a root `Grid` with all content in `Portrait` mode. I want to handle orientation in `Code` and by `Visual States`, but now when I rotate device, all content is automatically rotates and fill new width and height.

How can I disable this rotation behavior, i.e. disable `Portrait` orientation, but is still be able to get events about orientation changes?

Also, `Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.AutoRotationPreferences` doesn't seems to work

Comment: Hi have you got any better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Double click the "Package.appxmanifest" file in your metro app project, you should see configurations of your app.  In the "Application UI" page, you can find "Supported rotations" in the middle.  You can check the mode you supported, and leave the "Portrait" mode unchecked.  Then you app will not receive any "portrait" mode events anymore.

If you write your own appx manifiest, you can add following block under  section, like this

```
    <InitialRotationPreference>
      <Rotation Preference="landscape" />
      <Rotation Preference="portraitFlipped" />
      <Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
    </InitialRotationPreference>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem is I need to receive orientation changes events, but disable automatic changes in layout when orientation is changed

Comment: Also be aware that the Simulator does NOT respect these settings. You must test these on an actual device!! God knows why. Hopefully Microsoft will sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

When Windows says you're in portrait mode, add a rotatetransform to your root element that counters that and keeps things rendered portrait

Comment: but root element fill new layout size, i.e. `height` and `width` are swapped, and after rotation root element will not take all available space and will crop on sides also

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed your primary question. I don't think you can change the "rotation" of the root element after the portrait mode event. Because its actually not rotated relative to the screen, but screen size is changed.

However, I suppose you still want the user to look at your app in landscape mode after the portrait mode event. You can counter the perceived rotation. You can put you business logic in another user control with no predefined size. Put this user control in the root page. When you received the portrait mode event, you assign page ActualWidth to user control height, page ActualHeight to user control Width, the give user control a render transform of 90 degrees and render transform center x=height*0.707/width, y=0.5, then user control should just align to the landscape mode position.

Comment: I thought about such approach before but after rotation I get an cropped control on sides. Maybe some workaround exists but short research doesn't give me a result.