# Not able to lock the app to landscape orientation in Win8.1 C# app

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, device-orientation

The app was initially made for win 8. With the release of 8.1, I have updated both Visual Studio and Windows to 2013 and 8.1 respectively. 
The visual studio had asked me to upgrade the app to win8.1 which I have done.

My problem is simple, I cant lock the app to landscape orientation. Event though I have set the supported orientation to Landscape in the Package.appmanifest, When I flip it to portrait mode, all the UI is realigned!!

Can I no more lock the app to a particular orientation? Or am I missing something??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle orientations in Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260042/handle-orientations-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't resolved the issue yet, I was able to lock it to any orientation by using SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences function that can be imported from User32.dll.  Check [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn376361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.